# actionmailer / gmail / rails 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Has anybody been able to get actionmailer working with gmail under rails 2.3.2?

In 2.2.2 you needed to have a tls plugin, however my plug-in now does not work with 2.3.2.

If I take out the plug-in I get the error:

530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. h2sm5768861fkh.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this option on your smtp_setting in production.rb:

```
:enable_starttls_auto => true
```

If it doesn't work you can try to install a gem (keeping the option in your smtp_setting):

```
sudo gem install ambethia-smtp-tls -v '1.1.2' --source http://gems.github.com
```